# Can't identify source code for validation message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, email

I'm using a free Bootstrap theme. It has a contact form that automatically validates the email field and produces a corresponding tooltip error message.

I want to disable this validation but I can't identify it in the source code.

## Live example:

[Link](http://webthemez.com/preview/?neu-free-web-designer-profile-responsive-web-template)

## Code:

```
<input type="email" title="Please enter a valid email address" placeholder="Enter email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control">
```

## To reproduce:

1. Go to link.
2. Click "CONTACT US" link or scroll to page bottom.
3. Input "x" into the email field.
4. Click submit button.

## What I've tried:

I've searched all documents for the terms "email" and the provided error message.

- "email" led me to a modernizr document that has "prebaked" email validation. I removed the appropriate code to no avail.
- Searching for the provided error message yielded no results.

I've also reviewed the console via Firebug when submitting the form but nothing seems to be occurring.

How can I identify the required source code in order to disable it?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for the education and links. Requisite code provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's HTML 5 validation as per the browser, not jQuery or JavaScript.  To disable HTML 5 validation, simply add [the `novalidate` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#Attributes) to the `form` tag.

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" ...
```

This will disable HTML 5 validation on the whole form.  Presumably, if you don't want validation on one field, then you probably don't want it on any of them.

Otherwise, to disable validation on one field, then you need to remove any HTML 5 validation attributes on a per field basis.

Comment: Thanks. As validation only occurs on the email field, I opted for your second approach by changing the input type from email to text.